# CSS removing white space in a specific situation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Take a look at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTxQf/18/

When you click on the body of the lower right box, "TOO" is appended to the ul and animated upwards. This results in white space being added to #window-frame. I do not want this. I want no gap between "TOO" and "NEXT ITEM". Can this be done using CSS? I'd rather not fool with heights using JS. Also, any insight as to why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I think I can see what you're trying to achieve is it applicable to remove anything like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DTxQf/28/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `margin-top` instead of animating the `top` property:

```
$('#latest-image-list').animate({marginTop: "-=20"}, "fast");
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DTxQf/27/

Also, on a side-note, you created the `height` variable without the `var` statement which put it in the global scope (otherwise it would have been inside the `window.load` event handler scope). Always use `var` to make sure you aren't creating global variables unnecessarily (which creates extra overhead each time the variable is looked-up).

Comment: You're Welcome. I was just looking at the code again and noticed that the newly added list-items are `30px` tall and you are only reducing the height of the `<ul>` element by `20px` which means that each click pushes the "Next Item" text down `10px`.

Answer (score 4):

If the list must be relatively positioned, animate marginTop instead of top.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/DTxQf/34/)

Comment: I added a JSFiddle to your answer. Hope you're not mad at me.

Answer (score 0):

This should explain: http://jsfiddle.net/DTxQf/32/

Where is `MOO`? Not visible (under the top fold), but still there.
Despite translating the list up by 20px, it still takes the same space.